# Install older version of MS Office without removing newer version first

Tags: microsoft-excel, installation, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm currently running Microsoft Office 2010, but I temporarily need Excel 2007. I know I can use the `Custom` setup at the 2007 install process to select just Excel, and based on the `Setup Help` page:

> When you are done choosing the custom installation options that you want, do one of the following:
>
> - Click **Upgrade**. This button appears if Setup detects an earlier version of the same Office program on your computer.
> - Click **Install Now**. This button appears if Setup does not detect an earlier version of the same Office program on your computer.

I should use the `Upgrade` button to accomplish this. My problem however: I run a higher version and want to install a lower one, and this `Upgrade` button isn't available during the custom installation.
Also, based on [this page; nr. 2](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN289087/EN), it is recommended to first install all lower versions and then all higher:

> 2. You would need to install the oldest version of Office first (for example, Office 2003 would need to be installed before Office 2010). This would also apply to any standalone Office programs, i.e. Word or Excel. This is necessary as the registry keys, shared programs, and file extensions are managed separately for each version.

Still, I'd like to avoid having to install 2010 completely again, just because I temporary need Excel 2007 for a week. Is there really no way to just install Excel 2007 without having to uninstall and re-install 2010?

---

EDIT:

The reason I need Excel 2007 is because of a bug in Excel 2010 and 2013's `Import from Text / Website` features with our RavenDB database. [I've contacted RavenDB about this, and they are investigating the issue](http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-3897#comment=67-9218) (although I believe the issue is in Excel 2007+ itself, since there is nothing wrong with the Http-requests, nor JSON, nor headers, nor Content-Type of the RavenDB's calls).

Since we previously made these `Import from Text` in Excel 2007 and we are still able to open these existing Excels with our newer 2010 / 2013 versions (but unable to make them in 2010 / 2013), I want to temporary use Excel 2007 to create a few new `Import from Text` Excels, so we can then freely use the imported data in Excel 2010 / 2013 with the created connection still intact. I would prefer it if the `Import with Text` feature would just work with Excel 2010 / 2013, but since it doesn't, using Excel 2007 to create the data-connection is the best work-around for now.

Comment: There is no other way per the documentation you have provided.  [If you only need it for a week use a virtual machine with a trial installation of Windows.](https://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/)

Comment: @Ramhound Would I still be able to contact my localhost:8080 in the Virtual Machine? (I've made an edit to the original post to explain why I need Excel 2007.)

Comment: If you had a website running on the website, yes, you could connect to itself.  But you are expanding the scope of your question.